# Can OpenCV functions be called in C programs?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'd like to use some [SVD](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/df/df7/classcv_1_1SVD.html) functions to perform the similarity transform operators, but how do I achieve that using pure C code? Or is this impossible?

I tried mixed C and C++ code, but got this compilation error:
`"#error core.hpp header must be compiled as C++"`.

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: OpenCV 2.0+ is a C++-only library. OpenCV 1.0 used to work in C, too. Some older APIs still exist for C but are no longer actively developed. If you need to call it from C, you will need to create your own wrapper in C++.

Comment: look into [OpenVX](https://www.khronos.org/openvx/). or do a wrapper, as Konrad said. you'd make a cpp file where you write, and **export as C**, some functions that have "C" signatures (no class type arguments/results), but inside of which you do the necessary C++. this is a general technique and you'll find plenty of examples online.